# mixins jade/pug in jinja2(Nunjucks)

Tags: pug, jinja2, nunjucks

Is it possible to realize the mixins from jade in jinja?

```
 mixin navbar()
+b.NAV.navbar&attributes(attributes)
   block

+navbar
   p | some text
```

**Output:**

```
<nav><p>some text</p></nav>
```

Comment: Hi, I think you're looking for jinja macros.

Answer (score 1):

You may be looking for [Jinja macros](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/2.9/templates/#macros). They too take arguments, but not a block, and they can be imported from another file, with or without the current context.